# What subset of $[0,1]$ do we get corresponding to getting $0$ on the nth place in the base $4$ expansion of x in $[0,1]$?

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I need to test the Borel principle for the event of moving in the east direction on the nth move, where we move east if a four sided die lands $0$, west if it lands $1$, north if it lands $2$ and south if it lands $3$.
Then, the Borel principle says that the probability of any event is the Lebesgue measure of the subset of $[0,1]$ corresponding to that event, but I'm unable to find the corresponding set in the case of this event. Although, I can clearly see that the probability of this event is $1/4$.

Comment: Those would be the numbers in the interval $[0,1/4)$.

Comment: You're right I've edited it!

Answer (score 0):

Well. It is quite easy once you have figured out that Borel principle can be used here.

Consider     $w=0.a_1a_2a_3... $   in base 4, i.e. $a_i\in \{0,1,2,3\}$

The sets that fulfill the required condition $(a_n=0)$ are given by

$ (0.a_1a_2...a_{n-1}0000....,0.a_1a_2...a_{n-1}1000....) $ for all valid $a_is$ in $1\le i<n$

So, there are $4^{n-1}$ disjoint subsets in $[0,1]$ for this event. Measure of each subset is equal to $4^{-n}$.

Eg: first subset is $(0,0.00...\ (n-1\ zeros)\ 0... 1)_4$.

Last subset is $(0.33...\ (n-1\ threes)\ 3...0,0.33...\ (n-1\ threes)\ 3...1)_4$

Total probability = $4^{n-1} \cdot 4^{-n} = 0.25$ as expected.